# How to print an array within an array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this array that's driving me crazy, how can I print it? Using `print_r` shows it as a 2D array, but I can't output it with nested for loops, 
`$m_a[0][1]` gives nothing, and `$m_a[1]` returns a Array to string error.

```
$m_a = array(
        array(20347598, true),
        array(0, true),
        array(1, true),
        array(2, true),
        array(3, true),
        array(4, false),
        array(5, true),
        array(6, false),
        array(7, false),
        array(8, true),
        array(9, false),
        array(100, false),
        array(110, false),
        array(120, false),
        array(550, true),
        array(6100, true),
        array(123450, false),
        array(750250, true),
        array(8320400, true),
        array(92274650, true),
    );
```

Comment: `var_dump()` is the way

Comment: But what if I want to work with each individual array inside? like if I want to work with array(100, false) and just that 1.? O.o

Comment: Then you need to loop over the array. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php and http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1):

Try

var_dump($m_a);

var_dump is a great function to know when learning PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
foreach ($m_a as $arr) {
    print_r($arr);
}
```

If you want to print out the inner arrays individually, you can do this:

```
foreach ($m_a as $arr) {
     foreach($arr as $v) {
          print_r($v."\n");
     }
}
```

If you really want to use `$i` and `$j`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($m_a); $i++) {
     for ($j = 0; $j < count($m_a[$i]); $j++) {
          print_r($m_a[$i][$j]."\n");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
foreach ($m_a as $key) {
   echo $key[0] . " - " . $key[1] . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($m_a as $foo) {
    print_r($foo);
}
```

If you prefer, instead of `print_r($foo)` you could do `echo "$foo[0], $foo[1] \r\n"` to display the values.

Answer (score 0):

How do you trying to output $m_a[0][1]?

```
var_dump($m_a[0][1]);
```

Works perfectly fine

```
Vlads-MacBook-Pro:~ vmiller$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled
php > $m_a = array(
php (         array(20347598, true),
php (         array(0, true),
php (         array(1, true),
php (         array(2, true),
php (         array(3, true),
php (         array(4, false),
php (         array(5, true),
php (         array(6, false),
php (         array(7, false),
php (         array(8, true),
php (         array(9, false),
php (         array(100, false),
php (         array(110, false),
php (         array(120, false),
php (         array(550, true),
php (         array(6100, true),
php (         array(123450, false),
php (         array(750250, true),
php (         array(8320400, true),
php (         array(92274650, true),
php (     );
php > var_dump($m_a[0][1]);
bool(true)
php > echo $m_a[0][1];
1php > print $m_a[0][1];
1php >
```